# How to make a NSFW command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and I want a NSFW command in, so I used a command that's puts a random image of a NSFW subreddit, but I need help with the detection of a NSFW channel, so this command can't be used in channels that are not nsfw, and also send a message that says "You need to use this command in a nsfw channel!"
Here's my command, but there's a error in the part of "else:"

```
async def nsfw(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.is_nsfw():
        embed = discord.Embed(title="test", description="test")  
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
       await ctx.send("You need to use this command in a nsfw channel!"
```

Comment: What error are you having?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check to see if the channel the command is being used in is NSFW

```
 @commands.command()
 @commands.is_nsfw()
 async def your_nfsw_command(self, ctx):
    #your-command
```

As for throwing an error if the command is used in a non-nsfw channel, you can use a error handler such as

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.errors.NSFWChannelRequired):
     msg.title = "NSFW Command"
     msg.description = error.args[0]
     return await ctx.send(embed=msg)
```

Alternatively you may also add an error-handler by doing
`commandname.error` and using the same logic.

Possible corrections to code may involve:

```
if ctx.channel.is_nsfw():
  #logic
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
  #this line seems to be not indented correctly
else:
  #logic
```

Your error is likely thrown by an `else` without an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are missing paranthesis in else statement

> Code

```py
async def nsfw(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.is_nsfw():
        embed = discord.Embed(title="test", description="test")  
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
       await ctx.send("You need to use this command in a nsfw channel!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I used to get the same thing before, but researching I found the solution, I hope it helps you.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_nsfw()
async def nsfw(ctx):
embed = discord.Embed(title="test", description="test")
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/nsfw/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
res = await r.json()
embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@nsfw.error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, NSFWChannelRequired):
  await ctx.send(f"Hey! {ctx.author.mention}, sorry but i can't submit nsfw content without nsfw category.")
```